# How do I show a list within a pop-up box above a button using show by?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

**My list view:**

```
Ext.define("SenchaMaint2.view.MenuList", {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.menulist',

    requires: [

    ],

    config: {
        layout: 'fit',        
        items: [
            {                
                xtype: 'list',                                           
                itemTpl: [
                    '<div>{MenuItem}</div>'
                ],               
                store: 'menuListStore'
            }            
        ]
    }
});
```

How do I get this to show in a panel pop-up above a docked to bottom toolbar button?  I'm getting the reference to the list ok in my controller.  Am using the showBy() method against the button, but all I get is a tiny arrow with no populated panel. I know the list is populating as I've displayed the whole list in the view to test. It seems there is something wrong with the 'fit' layout when using a list in a pop-up?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying width & height of list like this:

```
Ext.define("SenchaMaint2.view.MenuList", {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
alias: 'widget.menulist',

requires: [

],

config: {
    layout: 'fit',  
    height: 200,
    width: 200,      
    items: [
        {                
            xtype: 'list',                                           
            itemTpl: [
                '<div>{MenuItem}</div>'
            ],               
            store: 'menuListStore'
        }            
    ]
}
});
```

then show by button like this:

```
menulist.showBy(button, "tl-bl?");
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is there any way to have the panel grow to as many items are in the list without fixing the width & height?

Comment: Panel can only grow upto viewport's height, anything more than that would result in scrolling list so its not a bad idea to have a fixed height list and let it scroll. BTW you can try using `minHeight` & `maxHeight` config